# How to add pre-defined values to Pair Hashmap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, tuples

I know how to add values to a hashmap, but what if the hashmap contains a Pair tuple.

I tried the following

```
private HashMap<String, Pair<String,String>> s = new HashMap<String, Pair<String, String>>() {{put("New York",("US Dollar", "NYC"));
    }};
```

It provides an error stating:

> Multiple markers at the line
>
> - Syntax error on token ",", invalid Assignment Operator
> - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: Don't use that "double-brace" style; it has all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Java syntax support for creating a Pair construct in Java, such as a map literal.  If you place `"US Dollar", "NYC"` in parentheses as you've done, then the compiler will assume that there is some kind of expression.  It finds the comma and complains that there is no assignment operator.  In reality, other operators are possible such as `+`, but that's the message the compiler gives.  The parser just went down the "assignment expression" possibility in the parse tree, trying to make sense of what turned out to be a syntax error.

Assuming you already have created your own `Pair` class that is already in scope, just create the `Pair` explicitly with `new`.  (You can use the diamond operator, available since Java 7, to shorten your code.)

```
private HashMap<String, Pair<String, String>> s = new HashMap<>() {{
    put("New York", new Pair<>("US Dollar", "NYC"));
}};
```

Using this "double-brace" initialization may work, but only because it

1. Creates an anonymous subclass of `Hashmap` with the outer braces.
2. Creates an instance initializer with the inner braces, which you use to initialize the map.

As of Java 9, you can use [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V)) to specify a `Map` with specific values, without the overhead of an extra anonymous class.

```
private Map<String, Pair<String,String>> s = Map.of("New York", new Pair<>("US Dollar", "NYC"));
```

You may also want to consider creating your own meaningful class to use instead of a general-use `Pair` class.

Comment: Thanks @rgettman. This worked. One more question, if I needed to add multiple values, do i do
put("New York", new Pair<>("US Dollar", "NYC"));
put("New York1", new Pair<>("US Dollar", "NYC"));
put("New York2", new Pair<>("US Dollar", "NYC"));

Comment: You can make all the `put` calls you want; they're just method calls.  If you use `Map.of`, you can supply up to 10 key/value pairs, e.g. `Map.of("New York", new Pair<>("US Dollar", "NYC"), "London", new Pair<>("UK Pound", "LON"), "Tokyo", new Pair<>("Japanese Yen", "TOK"));`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 9 you can use `Map.of`:

```
Map<String, Pair<String,String> values = Map.of("New York", new Pair<>("US Dollar", "NYC"));
```

I don't know what `Pair` is since there's no `Pair` class in default JDK but I'm assuming it has a constructor which accepts both values.

Your approach creates an anonymous class which also has a reference to the enclosing object so that's not a good solution.